# What is the energy of a (conduction/valence) band?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I'm trying to figure out what determines the energy of the bands, either conduction or valence band. Mostly I can read about the bandgap energy, which is mostly just the difference between $ E_C $ and $ E_V $ but there are also more concise expressions [like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) $ E_g(T) = E_g(0) - \frac{ \alpha \cdot T^2 }{T + \beta} $. According to wiki, $ E_g(0) $ is "just" a material constant.

In short words: What determines $ E_V $ and $ E_C $ ?

Comment: Consider where the Fermi energy is and how it is defined.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy it is subject to volume and the number of particles?
Is that the answer?

Comment: Kronig-penney model is a good exercise .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really it depends how deep you want to go! I hopefully will keep it fairly simple.
If you consider an atom, the energy levels are determined by the orbital the electron is in, calculated from the Schrodinger wave equation. It is a similar concept for a material, albeit complicated by there being a large number more atoms and the interactions between them. It should be noted here that these energy levels also vary periodically throughout the lattice.

Essentially this means that Ev and Ec are determined by the solution to the electron wavefunction for the highest occupied and lowest unoccupied energy band in the material.

Comment: Thanks, to be a bit more precise: The bands are a solution of the superpositions of (all) electron wavefunctions, or?
Not that of a single atom.

Comment: I'm going to use the wikipedia definition, because I think it sums it up quite nicely. The bands come from a single electron in a large, periodic lattice of atoms or molecules  - [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure).

Comment: If you want to go even deeper the commenter above who spoke about particle in a one dimensional lattice is a good start - I'm afraid I'm more of an applied semiconductor physicist, if you wanted to go even deeper I would suggest framing it using a quantum mechanics tag.

Comment: Thanks again, I will move to the article but nevertheless, before that, I'd like to raise a question: This means these bands already emerge even without the presence of any electron. Therefore, it is only a result of the presence of the cores then. I didn't expect that. 

As an applied semiconductor physicist, I would like to adress another question to you :) Are the bands temperature dependent? So far I only see any temperature dependency for the fermi energy but it's quite likely that I oversee something(?).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I completely understand - the bands wouldn't be there if there wasn't an electron, as the wavefunction is based on electrons, and the effect of the cores on them. As far as temperature dependence, a change in temperature will change the vibration of the lattice, meaning the bands will change too.

Comment: Indeed, that's obvious. Do you know how this mathematically takes place (the temperature)? From an applied perspective: Does it matter that the bands change with temperature? It is only the band gap that matters, or?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the maths behind it! With regards to any effect of the change in bands, it is often very small so is unlikely to have a huge effect. I will take solar cells as an example (largely as its my main area): in order to get efficient charge transfer through the cell, you need good band edge alignment with the contact layers - so a change in the band levels may affect this either positively or negatively. This may also have an affect on a heterojunction. However I would say the band gap plays a much bigger role - or its affects are more obvious/easier to observe

Comment: When the band gap plays a much bigger role resp. when it can be influenced more easily, then this should be valid for the bands as well, or not? Since the band gap is a subject to the conduction and valence bands. One of them, or both in parallel somehow.., must change with temperature.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't very clear - what I mean is that a change in the band gap, affecting open-circuit voltage will be a much more obvious change than mismatched band edges. It's also a lot easier to measure through a simple UV/Vis measurement with temperature.